# Why are orthogonal Latin Square defined the way they are?

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

Two Latin square of the same size are said to be orthogonal if you form a square by superimposing the two squares in the following way,
$\left[\begin{array}{l}1&2&3\\3&1&2\\2&3&1\end{array}\right]*$
$\left[\begin{array}{l}1&3&2\\3&2&1\\2&1&3\end{array}\right]=$
$\left[\begin{array}{l}1,1&2,3&3,2\\3,3&1,2&2,1\\2,2&3,1&1,3\end{array}\right]$ you get all possible pairs as entries , i.e all entries are distinct. My initial guess was that this somehow captures the idea of forming new latin sqaures by permuting rows and columns of a given latin squares.So that two squares are orthogonal if they cannot be converted into each other by permuting rows or columns. But this is not true as you can see,
$\left[\begin{array}{l}1&2&3\\3&1&2\\2&3&1\end{array}\right]*\left[\begin{array}{l}1&2&3\\2&3&1\\3&1&2\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{l}1,1&2,2&3,3\\3,2&1,3&2,1\\2,3&3,1&1,2\end{array}\right]$

I am not able to find the motivation behind defining the orthogonality condition on Latin squares.

Comment: Please state the orthogonality condition in your question.

Comment: This is a perfectly clear question to those who know what orthogonal Latin squares are. It asks about the motivation for certain terminology; it asks why the word *orthogonal* is used to describe such pairs of Latin squares. Please don't vote to close it.

Comment: I've added a few details. How do I reactivate this question?

Comment: I've voted to reopen. @GerryMyerson: You could as well.

Comment: Have you looked at [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square)?

Comment: @joriki, sorry, it was three in the morning here when you voted. But it seems my vote was not needed, m.se went on while I slept.

Comment: @joriki I guess looking at the applications will clarify things.